# How can I change a jQuery modal to a React modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm working on creating a button that only shows up if a certain parameter is true. I originally coded it in jQuery and React but I need to change it over to only React.
Here is the code with jQuery:

```
currentGame() {

    if (gameInfo.publicPlayersState.find(player => player.userName === userInfo.userName)) {
      $(this.inCurrentGame).modal('show');
    } else {
     return
    }

    function currentGameFnctn() {
        window.location.hash = `/${game._id}`;
    }



    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div
                ref={c => {
                    this.inCurrentGame = c;
                }}
            >
                <button className="ui primary button currentGame-button" onClick={this.currentGameFnctn}>
                    Current Game
                </button>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

This code checks if a person is sitting in a game, and if they are then a button should appear in their profile allowing another person looking at their profile to go to that game. If the person is not in a game then the button should not appear.

How would I change this to React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to achieve it with the `&&` operator :

```
currentGame() {
    function currentGameFnctn() {
        window.location.hash = `/${game._id}`;
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div
                ref={c => {
                    this.inCurrentGame = c;
                }}
            >
                {player.userName === userInfo.userName && 
                    <button className="ui primary button currentGame-button" onClick={this.currentGameFnctn}>
                        Current Game
                    </button>
                }
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!